# Why are Maven Goals not added by IntelliJ?

Tags: maven-2, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I have produced a new Maven Project from gae-archetype-gwt from within IntelliJ, and everything is generated well, but the gae:... goals won't show up in the Maven View, and if I try to update Repository Indices, apart from the local repository I get errors only.
When I run gae:unpack from terminal, everything works fine.
Im running Ubuntu 10.04 Beta 1 and am using open-jdk, for which IntelliJ is also configured.

**UPDATE: WORKS FINE WITH UBUNTU 10.04 FINAL + JDK FROM PARTNER REPOSITORY**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem. Please create a request in JetBrains YouTrack and describe your environment (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues).

Thanks,

Anton Makeev,
IntelliJ IDEA Developer